# Over the range microwave oven fan speed is the same in all settings

Tags: appliances

New microwave swap out  with new one but fan is loud, &  speed is the same in all3 settings panasonic  nn se284b over the range microwave oven

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If this is a new oven, contact the manufacturer; they'll know more than us. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yes don’t mess with a new product take it back.